# How to declare a Typescript array that will always be empty?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I'm declaring a private default inside a module. The value is an empty array. It will *always* be empty, because it's kind of a fallback value. TS wants me to type the array, but it seems I *shouldn't* declare what kinds of value the array will hold, because this function is used by many callers, each of whom works with different kinds of data.

I've got something like this:

```js
const DATA_FOR_ERROR_CASES = []

export default function unpackData( packedData: string|undefined ) {
  if(packedData === undefined) {
    // return a Node-style callback tuple
    return [
      new TypeError('missing packedData'),
      DATA_FOR_ERROR_CASES.slice()
    ]
  }
  /*
    Otherwise, do really complex stuff, which can generate an
    array OR a hash, depending on the string content of packedData
  */
  return [
    undefined, // as in Node, error arg is undefined in success case
    unpackedData
  ]
}
```

I use an empty array as my default return because experimentation suggests this will permit callers to optimistically destructure it regardless whether they're expecting a hash or a list in success cases. Like so:

```js
// one caller knows it'll get a hash (if things don't break)
let [ error, { name, address } ] = unpackData(packedContact)

// another caller expects an actual list
let [ error, [ firstChoice, secondChoice, ...otherChoices ] ] = unpackData(packedPrefs)
```

If unpacking fails, the first element will be some helpful Error instance, and the second value will be `DATA_FOR_ERROR_CASES`.

In error cases, the second example fails if `DATA_FOR_ERROR_CASES` is a hash, because you can't use array-destructuring on a POJO. You *can* use both array- and property-destructuring on an array. I want callers to be able to optimistically destructure, rather than having to do this:

```js
// this sucks because it's so awkward
let [ error, unpacked ] = unpackData(packedPrefs)
if(error) throw error // ... or bail in some other way, preventing next line

let [ firstChoice, secondChoice, ...otherChoices ] = unpacked
```

My question: **how should I declare the type of `DATA_FOR_ERROR_CASES`?**

TS won't accept this:

```
const DATA_FOR_ERROR_CASES: Array = []
// Generic type 'Array<T>' requires 1 type argument(s). ts(2314)
```

Comment: Why not `const DATA_FOR_ERROR_CASES = [] as const;`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I thought I had tried that with no success, but when I do it now, TS shuts up. If you'll put this in an answer, I'll consider selecting it this evening once I've canvassed the suggestions. And thanks!

Comment: Another poster suggested (in a now-deleted answer) declaring with `unknown` or `any`. Reading about the differences, I'm intrigued; each strikes me as a good fit for different reasons. I wonder if anyone (including that poster) would elaborate.

Comment: Well `any[]` or `unknown[]` wouldn't be empty, they'd have values for any index. Also note `DATA_FOR_ERROR_CASES.slice()` will be `never[]` if `DATA_FOR_ERROR_CASES` is `readonly []`, as `as const` makes it. Fundamentally I think the type of `DATA_FOR_ERROR_CASES` matters less than the actual return type for `unpackData`, maybe using overloads for example, but it's not entirely clear to me what outcomes you're looking for.